# How to get uniques and sum based on criteria set in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to get these summed, but I can't wrap my head around it.
Here is a visual demo:

[image]

Here is the link to the sheet, in case you feel like jumping in:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU/edit?usp=sharing

I did an INDEX+MATCH, but of course this isn't going to get me anywhere:

`=iferror(INDEX(E:E;MATCH(1;(F:F=I$6)*(A:A=$H$7);0));"-")`

Comment: Thanks, @halfer! I totally understand that keeping it concise, to the point, is key for quality purpose, but I can't seem to be able to discard thankfulness, if it helps me so much. We're interacting with people who put energy into helping and gatitude, politeness are such great values we share... Sad to have this flavor killed.

Comment: The discussion has been had _ad nauseum_, and the majority consensus (including moderators and staff) is technical writing and succinctness. I thus have this discussion every couple of weeks, in the comments, with someone who falls on the other side of the debate. I understand the perspective, but I tend to try to persuade people to characterise it a different way - gratitude is expressed via the tools provided - acceptance and upvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do two nested QUERY to find the uniques (by counting them), and only selecting them the column of numbers. The first QUERY also filters by date and type:

```
=SUM(QUERY(QUERY(A:F;"SELECT A,B,E,COUNT(A) where A = '"&H7&"' AND F = date'"&TEXT(I6;"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' group by A,B,E");"SELECT Col3"))
```

[image]

As an array to include more all the dates:

```
=MAKEARRAY(2;COUNTA(I6:6);LAMBDA(r;c;SUM(QUERY(QUERY(A:F;"SELECT A,B,E,COUNT(A) where A = '"&INDEX(H7:H8;r)&"' AND F = date'"&TEXT(INDEX(I6:6;;c);"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' group by A,B,E");"SELECT Col3"))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Added working solution to your [sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU/edit#gid=1070317396):

```
=MAKEARRAY(2;COUNTA(I6:O6);LAMBDA(r;c;SUM(LAMBDA(z;MAP(INDEX(z;;1);INDEX(z;;2);INDEX(z;;3);LAMBDA(a;e;f;IFNA(FILTER(e;a=INDEX(H7:H8;r);f=INDEX(I6:O6;;c))))))(UNIQUE({A:A\E:E\F:F})))))
```

- 

[image]